# What is wrong with this jQuery if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

The goal of this page is to show different options based on the drop down selection.  The toggle is currently working as desired without the if statement in place.  How can I adjust my if statement to do the correct comparison?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/SearchInventory.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
            var selection = $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());
            if(selection =='Projectors') {
                $('#projectorSearch').toggle();
            }
        });
    });
</script>




<h2>Search Inventory</h2>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-lg" type="button" id="dropDownSelectItemType" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                    Select an Item Type
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labeledby="dropDownSelectItemType">
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Projectors</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Desktop Printers</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Network Printers</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Tablets</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Televisions</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Polycom Phones</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cameras</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Monitors</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Leased Printers</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cell Phones</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Chair(ergo)</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Keyboard(ergo)</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Mouse(ergo)</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Footrest(ergo)</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Licensed Software</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Desk Phones</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="projectorSearch" id="projectorSearch">
        <label>onomonpeia</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .find('.selection') - where is class='selection'?

Comment: Simply use `var selection = $(this).text();`

Comment: `var selection = $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());` Shouldn't it be `var selection =$(this).text();`?

Comment: @Scottie good point, I'm the victim of a time crunch and had copied that line from another function without paying attention, thinking it was doing what i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to go arround to find the clicked `text` because you already have access to `HTMLAnchorElement` element referenced as `this`

Use

```
 var selection = $(this).text();
```

Instead of

```
 var selection = $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());
```

The full example:

```
$(function () {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function () {
        var selection = $(this).text();
        if(selection =='Projectors') {
            $('#projectorSearch').toggle();
        }
});
```

Here is a [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/297wth3w/)

Answer (score 1):

you did well, but missed one thing.

```
var selection = $(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());
```

this line will change text of .selection. but doesn't return $(this).text()

so you have to compare $(this).text() with string, not selection.

or just redefine the selection again, like these 2 lines.

```
$(this).parents(".btn-group").find('.selection').text($(this).text());
var selection = $(this).text()
```